# How to load local image to meta tag in html with webpack

Tags: html, vue.js, webpack, meta

I have a meta tag that should look like this

```
<meta property="og:image" content="https://mywebsite/img.jpg" />
```

I can't just set it to be `'./images/img.jpg'`

I use webpack to compile my background images from my vue app so I can load this image somewhere in my template as background and then set it `index.html` in build folder. But it seems strange to do so and also webpack hashes images so they have different names after every build.

Is there a way out? Can I use `HtmlWebpackPlugin` maybe for this?

Comment: Maybe `'../images/img.png'` (Note the 2 dots)? Also check [this guide](https://medium.com/a-beginners-guide-for-webpack-2/handling-images-e1a2a2c28f8d) for handling images via webpack

Comment: Did you find a solution to this?

Comment: @ARaj123 yes, I did like below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I think I solved the problem with this line of code in my index.html (not in build folder)

```
<meta property="og:image" content="<%= require('./images/img.jpg') %>" />
```

Comment: Could you specify which modules you are then using for the bundling?

Comment: did FB found the image? Did you get a full path of the image? I get only relative

Comment: FYI this is the standard HtmlWebpackPlugin (https://github.com/jantimon/html-webpack-plugin). For control of prefix, use the `publicPath` webpack config (HtmlWebpackPlugin also has, but rather use the generic webpack one). You probably want to set the publicPath to different values based on args.mode - say just to `/` for development, but your CDN prefix for production.